# Getting The Correct Position of an Item inside a JCombobox in Java

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

To get the position of an Item inside the combobox I typically use the `getSelectedIndex()` method, however this method no longer works when you have Items that are **equal**.

**Example**:

Suppose we have the following items in our `JCombobox`: `{Harry , John , Mary , Harry}` then when selecting `Harry`(the fourth item of the combobox) we do not get the correct output which should be: `3` but instead we get `0` (the position of the first Item).

The `JCombobox` implementation lets us add items that are equal but we still get this behaviour when we try to get their position inside the `JCombobox` using the `getSelectedIndex()` method.

So is there a way to get the correct position or index of an Item that is equal to another item in the `JCombobox`?

Comment: according to oracle it's expected behavior.i found this code from coderanch.it seems to be working.https://coderanch.com/t/334611/GUI/java/Duplicate-items-JCombobox

Comment: Wrap the items within a custom class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the data within a custom class. You can override `toString` and return the data object for display by the `JComboBox`. For example:

```
public class MyClass{

    private String myName;

    public MyClass(String name){
        this.myName = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return myName;
    }

}

myComboBox.add(new MyClass("Harry"));
myComboBox.add(new MyClass("John"));
myComboBox.add(new MyClass("Mary"));
myComboBox.add(new MyClass("Harry"));
```

The first and last objects will not be equal, according to their `equals` method - which leads to an important point: be sure the implementation of `MyClass` does not override `equals`, as this method is used by `getSelectedIndex` to get the index of the element